# How to change bootstrap Button css onclick reactjs?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

Here 
I want to know that how i change color of bootstrap button on onclick function.
I have three button like word para and sentence. when i clicking on word button change the color of word button color and when i click on sentence button change the color of sentence button and toggle for same para.
 WHat should i do?

Comment: Where do you have your color defined? How are you deciding with color you have to apply to your button?

Comment: Are you using straight Bootstrap classes or an integration package such as react-boostrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how to change a buttons color without bootstrap
by using inline style.
Maybe this will get you closer to your solution.

```
let buttonsStyle = {
        background: "#eee",
        padding: "20px",
        margin: "20px"
      };

let selectedButtonStyle = {
        background: "blue",
        padding: "20px",
        margin: "20px"
      };

class Application extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = { selectedButtonId: 0 };
    this.selectButton = this.selectButton.bind(this);
  } 

  selectButton(id){

    this.setState({selectedButtonId: id});
  }

  render() {

    const buttonsList = [{name:'word', id:'1'}, {name:'para', id:'2'}, {name:'sentence', id:'3'}];

    const buttons = _.map(buttonsList, val => {

      const buttonStyle = val.id === this.state.selectedButtonId ? selectedButtonStyle : buttonsStyle;

      return (<button id={val.id} style={buttonStyle} onClick={() => { this.selectButton(val.id) }}> {val.name} </button>);
    });

    return (<div>
        {buttons}
      </div>);
  }
}


React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

By the best way to use react and bootstrap is to use react-bootstrap